# How to convert JsValue to a Model Class with Scala in Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to set up a JSON response that I got from a weather API to fit in a model class I defined in order to use it easily, but I can't get to do it.

Here is the class :

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Forecast(var main: String, var description: String, var temp: Int, var tempMin: Int, var tempMax: Int)

object Forecast {
  implicit val forecastJsonFormat: Reads[Forecast] = (
      (JsPath \ "weather" \\"main").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "weather" \\"description").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "main" \\"temp").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "main" \\"temp_min").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "main" \\"temp_max").read[Int]
    ) (Forecast.apply _)
}
```

and this is the code in the controller :

```
def weather = Action.async {
futureResponse.map(response => {
  val jsonString = response.json.toString()
  val jsonObject = Json.parse(jsonString)

  // TODO: Create t [Forecast] Object which represents the response.json data to send it to the view  below

  Ok(views.html.weather(t))
})}
```

example of the response.json I'am getting :

```
{"coord":{"lon":37.62,"lat":55.75},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13n"},{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":269.15,"pressure":1024,"humidity":92,"temp_min":268.15,"temp_max":270.15},"visibility":3100,"wind":{"speed":2,"deg":200},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1546266600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9029,"message":0.0029,"country":"RU","sunrise":1546235954,"sunset":1546261585},"id":524901,"name":"Moscow","cod":200}
```

Comment: added more information to my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got to do it and here is how :

In the model I have my case class defined and a companion object that parses the JSON response I got from the web API to my class arguments

Model code :

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Forecast(main: String, description: String, temp: Double, tempMin: Double, tempMax: Double)

object Forecast {
  implicit val forecastReads: Reads[Forecast] = (
      (JsPath \ "weather" \\ "main").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "weather" \\ "description").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "main" \ "temp").read[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "main" \ "temp_min").read[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "main" \ "temp_max").read[Double]
    ) (Forecast.apply _)
}
```

In the controller code I added a pattern matching and here it is !

Controller code :

```
def weather = Action.async {
    futureResponse.map(response => {
      val parseResult = Json.fromJson[Forecast](response.json)
      parseResult match {
        case JsSuccess(forecast, JsPath) => Ok(views.html.weather(forecast))
        case JsError(error) => InternalServerError("Something went wrong!!") // Note that I'm not sure this result exists in Play...
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `main` to `Seq[String]` and `description` to `Seq[String]` and `temp`, `tempMin`, `tempMax` to `Double`

I used a different way to create the `reads` here, but this way will throw an exception if the format is different than the expected format.

```
case class Forecast(main: Seq[String], description: Seq[String], temp: Double, tempMin: Double, tempMax: Double)

object Forecast {
    val reads = new Reads[Forecast] {
        override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Forecast] = {
            val main = (json \ "weather" \\ "main").map(_.as[String]).toList
            val description = (json \ "weather" \\ "description").map(_.as[String]).toList
            val temp = (json \ "main" \ "temp").as[Double]
            val tempMin = (json \ "main" \ "temp_min").as[Double]
            val tempMax = (json \ "main" \ "temp_max").as[Double]

            JsSuccess(Forecast(main, description, temp, tempMin, tempMax))
        }
    }
}
```

or you can use the same way you are using, but parse the list in different way:

```
val forecastJsonFormat: Reads[Forecast] = (
  (JsPath \ "weather").read[List[Map[String, JsValue]]].map(_.map(_("main").as[String])) and
    (JsPath \ "weather").read[List[Map[String, JsValue]]].map(_.map(_("description").as[String])) and
    (JsPath \ "main" \ "temp").read[Double] and
    (JsPath \ "main" \ "temp_min").read[Double] and
    (JsPath \ "main" \ "temp_max").read[Double]
  ) (Forecast.apply _)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mahmoud and happy new year
Can you please explain how I can create the object `t [Forecast]` using the class definition in my controller ?